# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays error

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular7

Backend (Spring Boot, REST(Spring Data Rest, Spring Data JPA) It's only happening with JPA, without it works perfectly, but a hella lot more code to write).

I tried all the remaining responses but I'm not getting the exact solution.

**BACKEND API**

```
New File
pizzatest.model.ts
export class Pizzas{

    firstName: string;
    description: string;
}

API BELOW   

_embedded   
pizzas  
0   
firstName   "Pizza Margarita"
description "Ingredients of Margarita"
_links  
self    
href    "http://localhost:8080/pizzas/1"
pizza   
href    "http://localhost:8080/pizzas/1"
1   
firstName   "Detroit Pizza"
description "Ingredients of Detroit Pizza"
_links  
self    
href    "http://localhost:8080/pizzas/2"
pizza   
href    "http://localhost:8080/pizzas/2"
2   
firstName   "Greek Pizza"
description "Ingredients of Greek Pizza"
_links  
self    
href    "http://localhost:8080/pizzas/3"
pizza   
href    "http://localhost:8080/pizzas/3"
3   
firstName   "Sicilian Pizza"
description "Ingredients of Sicilian Pizza"
_links  
self    
href    "http://localhost:8080/pizzas/4"
pizza   
href    "http://localhost:8080/pizzas/4"
4   
firstName   "Chicago Pizza"
description "Ingredients of Chicago Pizza"
_links  
self    
href    "http://localhost:8080/pizzas/5"
pizza   
href    "http://localhost:8080/pizzas/5"
_links  
self    
href    "http://localhost:8080/pizzas{?page,size,sort}"
templated   true
profile 
href    "http://localhost:8080/profile/pizzas"
page    
size    20
totalElements   5
totalPages  1
number  0
```

**SERVICE**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PizzatestService {

readonly rootUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getPizzas(){
  return this.http.get(this.rootUrl + '/pizzas');
}}
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PizzatestService } from './pizzatest.service';
import {Pizzas} from './pizzatest.model'; 


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pizzatest',
  templateUrl: './pizzatest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pizzatest.component.css']
})
export class PizzatestComponent implements OnInit {

pizzas : Pizzas[]


  constructor(private pizzaTestService: PizzatestService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
this.pizzaTestService.getPizzas().subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log('from service', data)
  this.pizzas = data;
})
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let pizza of pizzas">
        <ul> 
          <li> {{pizza.firstName}}</li>
          <li> {{pizza.description}}</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of your response in json format?

Comment: Can you show the `data` object

Comment: The structure is in JSON format, it's just that I'm using Spring REST(JPA) and it appears slightly different.

 firstName":"Pizza Margarita",
            "description":"Ingredients of Margarita"

Comment: 0: {firstName: "Pizza Margarita", description: "Ingredients of Margarita", _links: {…}}
1: {firstName: "Detroit Pizza", description: "Ingredients of Detroit Pizza", _links: {…}}
2: {firstName: "Greek Pizza", description: "Ingredients of Greek Pizza", _links: {…}}
3: {firstName: "Sicilian Pizza", description: "Ingredients of Sicilian Pizza", _links: {…}}
4: {firstName: "Chicago Pizza", description: "Ingredients of Chicago Pizza", _links: {…}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expect an array of objects, but I think what you get from the server is an object, which has a `pizzas` property. Try this way:

```
getPizzas(){
  return this.http.get(this.rootUrl + '/pizzas')
    .pipe(map(data => data.pizzas));
}}
```

You can check what you get from the server using

```
getPizzas(){
  return this.http.get(this.rootUrl + '/pizzas')
    .pipe(tap(console.log));
}}
```

(You can import `tap` the same way you did with `map`)

Comment: map gives me an error(annot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?) any idea how to fix it?

Yeah you're right, I got an object instead of what I'm expecting

Comment: If you use newer version of rxjs, you have to import it this way: `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: Thank you but now something else came up, data.pizzas(Property 'pizzas' does not exist on type 'Object'). Also now it wont even show on the consoleLog.

I'll research this one if I can find any solution on it

Comment: Then indeed, the problem is that what you get from the server is not an array. I edited my answer, I hope it helps you debugging.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your time, my problem has become clear now like they say the step towards a solution is first understanding you have a problem, and I know what it is, all I need to figure out now is to display object properties.

Answer (score 0):

Every return of data using HttpClient is in Json object format. For example:

[image]

Here's a sample code that you can try.

You can try to map your data inside the service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
  export class DataloadService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    LoadData(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .map(this.extractData)
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
      let body = res;
      return body;
    }

  }
```

Here's the app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {DataloadService} from './dataload.service';
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent {

  dataFromServer: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private load: DataloadService) {}

  getDataServer() {
    let obj = this.load.LoadData();
    obj.subscribe(data => {this.dataFromServer = data;
    console.log("data:", data);
    })
  };

  ngOnInit() {this.getDataServer();} 

}
```

The html file:

```
<h2>My Awesome Table:</h2>

<table *ngIf="dataFromServer">

  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let data of dataFromServer">
    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.name}}</td> 
    <td>{{data.username}}</td>
    <td>{{data.email}}</td> 
  </tr>

</table>
```

Hope this will help your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jess, I will look forward it as a future reference